# How to jump to a function under the cursor in emacs

Tags: emacs

I have two files: A.el and B.el

Under my cursor in A.el is a function defined in B.el. How do I jump to the function in B.el?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M-x find-function` does that.

> Finds the source file containing the definition of the function
> near point (selected by ‘function-called-at-point’) in a buffer and
> places point before the definition.

You seem to be asking specifically about native Emacs Lisp; you need to have loaded the function into Emacs for this to work.

In the general case, this depends on the mode of the file, but the traditional solution is to use [`etags`.](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags)
A somewhat more modern replacement called [`xref`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Xref.html#Xref) was introduced in Emacs 25; try <kbd>M-.</kbd>